# GCC cannot recognize the directory path inside a file

Tags: c, bash, makefile

The problem I encountered in using GCC is that I cannot use the command `make` to build my program because some files contain the paths of their actual location.

Say I have a file named "machine.h", its content is `target-pisa/pisa.h`. At the same time, in the same working directory, I have a folder named "target-pisa", in which there is a file named "pisa.h"; the actual code of the header file "machine.h" is actually inside the file "pisa.h", which is inside the folder named "target-pisa" located in the same working directory as "machine.h".

Assume for some reason I cannot simply copy and paste the code from "pisa.h" to "machine.h"; that is, I have to stick with what is provided by the prof. The `make` command does not work in this case in my laptop because it cannot interpret `target-pisa/pisa.h` as a directory path and open the actual header file "pisa.h" according to the path `target-pisa/pisa.h` provided in the file "machine.h". Instead, git bash interprets `target-pisa/pisa.h` as C code (if I am not mistaken); see the figure below.

[image]

Some additional info that may be helpful:

In `machine.h`, there is only one line of code as shown below:
`target-pisa/pisa.h`

I have checked that almost all `.c` files in the working directory have `#include "machine.h"`.

How can I solve this problem? Please help, I have been stuck in this for a long time. By the way, my friend also used git bash to do this lab and this problem doesn't happen to him.

I tried to reinstall git bash in order to see if the problem can be solved, but it didn't.

All in all, I want to build the program successfully by using `make` command in git bash.

Comment: read up on how `#include` works

Comment: Can you send the relevant code in `machine.h`? As jhnc said, I have a sneaking suspicion that you're not using #include.

Comment: In `machine.h`, there is only one line of code `target-pisa/pisa.h`. In the same working directory, I have `mian.c`, it has `#include "machine.h"`, does this help?

Comment: The problem is that my friend also uses the same set of files without any modifications and this problem does happen to him.

Comment: I have checked that almost all `.c` files in the working directory have `#include "machine.h"`.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of broken symlinks. Does your friend work with git-bash on Windows or with bash on Linux?

Comment: I think he probably works with git-bash on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`machine.h` needs to have an `#include` directive to tell the compiler to pull in the nested header.

```
#include "target-pisa/pisa.h"
```

Just writing `target-pisa/pisa.h` by itself isn't valid C code.

Comment: In the file `machine.def`, there is only one line of code that says `target-pisa/pisa.de`, should I change it to `#include "target-pisa/pisa.def"`; I am not sure if this is the proper way to do for a .def file. By the way, this .def is used in the file `Makefile`.